# Oracle Spatial: Issue with sdo_nn_distance for canada postal codes

Tags: oracle-spatial

Spatial data are available in the table st_country_postal_code with index. Inorder to get the distance between postal codes, we used the below query

```
SELECT sdo_nn_distance (1) distance, z.* 
FROM st_country_postal_code z
WHERE z.postal_code = UPPER ('V3G1M2')
   AND z.country_id = '124'
   AND 'TRUE' =
         sdo_nn (z.spatial_data,
                 (SELECT spatial_data
                    FROM st_country_postal_code
                   WHERE country_id = '124' AND postal_code = UPPER ('V2R0N3')),
                 'sdo_num_res=999 unit=' || 'KM', 
                 1
                );
```

For some canadian zipcodes, for the above query I am getting no rows returned like V2R0N3, V3G1M2 , J8H2A7. Is there a constraint for the sdo_nn function to not let calculate the distance?